# how is the error if the error is cannot implicitly convert type 'string ' to System.Window.Forms in c#

Tags: c#

[image]

I dont get it please help me in line of lblGrandTotal = ""; it said

> Cannot Implicitly convert type 'string ' to System.Window.Forms.Label

Comment: lblGrandTotal.Text= ""

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question instead of providing a link to an image.

Answer (score 4):

It should be as below :

```
lblGrandTotal.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the .Text property of the control lblGrandTotal:

```
lblGrandTotal.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

use `lblGrandTotal.Text = "yourText";`

You are trying to assign text to a Label object type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Text` property. Furthermore, it's better code if you do `lblGrandTotal.Text = string.Empty` rather than `""`. Nit picking, but better code.